# ERROR: Invalid configuration for file "/Users/hello/Documents/projects/hello_world/.eslintrc.json"

Tags: next.js, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

I'm getting this error message when I run the `npm run format` command in the root directory of my nextjs project:

```
[error] Invalid configuration for file "/Users/hello/Documents/projects/hello_world/.eslintrc.json":
[error] require() of ES Module /Users/hello/Documents/projects/hello_world/node_modules/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/dist/index.mjs not supported.
[error] Instead change the require of /Users/hello/Documents/projects/hello_world/node_modules/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/dist/index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

`.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "ignorePatterns": [".eslintrc.json"]
}
```

`prettier.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    bracketSpacing: true,
    semi: true,
    trailingComma: "all",
    printWidth: 80,
    tabWidth: 2,
    plugins: [require("prettier-plugin-tailwindcss")],
};
```

`package.json file`:

```
{
  "name": "hello_world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format:write": "prettier --write \"**/*.{css,js,json,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "format": "prettier \"**/*.{css,js,json,jsx,ts,tsx}\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // some dependencies
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-next": "latest",
    "postcss": "latest",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.4",
    "tailwindcss": "latest"
  }
}
```

File/Folder Structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tailwind sorting plugin isn't compatible with prettier v3.0.0. Here's how to downgrade:

Prettier v2.8.8:

Yarn: `yarn add prettier@2.8.8 -D`

NPM: `npm install prettier@2.8.8 --save-dev`

prettier-plugin-tailwindcss v0.4.0:

Along with downgrading Prettier, it's also necessary to downgrade the tailwindcss plugin for Prettier.

Yarn: `yarn add prettier-plugin-tailwindcss@0.4.0 -D`

NPM: `npm install prettier-plugin-tailwindcss@0.4.0 --save-dev`

Await updates for compatibility fixes.

Comment: such a great solution thanks man